# AWS X-Ray trace for SNS used in Lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, aws-xray

I have a AWS lambda function written in NodeJS, on which I enabled **Active Tracing**, and now I see the X-Ray trace every time it's called. But - the Lambda function also publishes to an SNS, and the SNS does not appear in the X-Ray traces.
Do I need to add code in order to see the SNS trace?

(The lambda and SNS are both using the same Role, so I think it's not the issue).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see more details inside your lambda function, you will need to make some changes on your function code. You can take a look at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-nodejs-awssdkclients.html for how to trace AWS SDK calls.